# no warning is given for a deprecated beheavior in c++11

Tags: c++11, g++, clang++

according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

> The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is
>   deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor or user-defined copy
>   assignment operator.

but the following code, no warning message is given using clang++ and c++

```
struct CAT
{
    CAT(){cout<<"CAT()"<<endl;}
    ~CAT(){}
};

int main()
{
    CAT c1, c2;
    CAT c3(c1); //should print out a warning?
}

clang++-3.6  -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  -O2 -o m main.cpp -pedantic-errors -std=c++14
```

Is it the expected behaviour of g++ and clang++?

Answer (score 1):

clang++ has this warning:

```
main.cpp:6:5: warning: definition of implicit copy constructor for 'CAT' is deprecated because it has a user-declared destructor [-Wdeprecated]
    ~CAT(){}
    ^
main.cpp:12:9: note: implicit copy constructor for 'CAT' first required here
    CAT c3(c1); //should print out a warning?
        ^
1 warning generated.
```

demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6b31ce2d56fac5a

Comment: I run the command in ubuntu  clang++/g++ -Wdeprecated -o test -std=c++14 -O3 -pedantic-errors main.cpp (clang++3.6, g++4.8.2),  but there is no warning.